# Error of invalid vertex names on induced subgraph igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph, vertex

I kept getting on this error: Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, vids) : Invalid vertex name(s); while trying to induced subgraph. I did it on different vertices attribute, and managed to get the intended induced subgraph. Yet, I'm unable to get the subgraph on this particular vertices attribute.
Here is the code:
`b<-induced_subgraph(snet,V(snet)$Daerah=="Sabak Bernam")`

The column Daerah contained many other value, all of the value come back as error.

Comment: Shouldn't  it be `b<-induced_subgraph(snet, names(V(snet))=="Sabak Bernam")`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example